# I forgot my Ubuntu user login password, I reset it but have also forgotten the login for the key ring, everything else in inactive

Tags: login, password

As per the original query…
I forgot my original password login for my existing user account, I reset the password in the grub root successfully but now it is asking for authentication required;

The password you use to log in to your computer no longer matches that of your login key ring.

Password:

Any help on how to reset this also?

I cannot access the terminal logged into the user as everything is inactive.

Much love to all
Ben

Comment: Is your Ubuntu installed with encrypted disk (LVM with LUKS encryption)? In that case you must rely on backups and/or your memory. Otherwise you can reset the password. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).

Comment: Thank you - I realised the page was no longer inactive however it is now powering up every other minute requesting a keyring password. I managed to reset the user account password so I am in, I will update Ubuntu to latest version this evening and I’m guessing this will resolve it as well. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck upgrading to the latest version :-) Please remember that things can go wrong during the upgrade to a new version, so backup everything that you cannot afford to lose.