# authentication pop-up

Tags: security

I did post about this before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423043/i-forgot-my-ubuntu-user-login-password-i-reset-it-but-have-also-forgotten-the-l)

I had to reset my login password in boot

I now have the authentication pop up popping up often

I believe this is affecting installations/updates but also I am just curious to resolve and improve my set-up.

The pop-up display states the following and often I must close 3 times before it disappears.

"The password you use to log in to your computer no longer matches that of your login key ring.

Password:"

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and am looking to update to the latest google-chrome.

**EDIT**: I believe this issue is interfering in google-chrome update as when I am trying to update google-chrome the pop up appears and then google chrome states that it was unable to update and that I will have chrome without improvements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop being prompted to unlock the 'default' keyring on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)

Comment: unfortunately not. When I go to keyring it states that there is a difference in my old and new password. I've just learned to accept it, and will update it when I can.